Why is the variance of sample mean equal $\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}$ and not $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$
The variance of a sum $\bar{X}$ of variables $X_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ is the sum of the variances
$\sigma_1^2 + ... + \sigma_n^2$
If the variables all have the same variance then the sum becomes $n\sigma^2$.
To compute the mean, I divide the sum by $n$.
Then, why is the variance of the sample mean $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$?
The explaination I found states:
$$\operatorname{Var}(\bar X) = \frac{1}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}\left(\sum_i X_i \right)$$
I don't know where that $n^2$ is coming from.

$\bar{X} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i}X_i$. However, note $Var(\sum_{i}X_i) = nVar(X_1)$, assuming $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are uncorrelated.

$\overline{X}$ is the sample mean $\frac{1}{n}\sum_i X_i$ not the sum $\sum_i X_i$

Two comments: 1. The variance of the sum is equal to the sum of the variances if the variables are uncorrelated. If they are not, you get additional covariance terms. 2. In general, if $X$ is absolutely square integrale, then $\operatorname{Var}(c X)=c^2 \operatorname{Var}(X)$ for $c\in\mathbb R$. You can derive this for instance from the Definition $\operatorname{Var}(X)=\mathbb E((X-\mathbb E(X))^2)$.

Third comment: The variance of $\bar X$ assuming the $X_i$ are iid is indeed $\frac{\sigma^2}n$ because $\frac{n}{n^2}=\frac 1n$.. It is not $\frac{\sigma^2}{n^2}$.

There are two properties of variance that are relevant.
Property 1:  For independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with finite variance, $$\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y].$$
Property 2:  For any scalar constant $c$ and random variable $X$ with finite variance, $$\operatorname{Var}[cX] = c^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].$$
The first property leads to the identity
$$\operatorname{Var}[X_1 + X_2 + \cdots + X_n] = \operatorname{Var}[X_1] + \operatorname{Var}[X_2] + \cdots + \operatorname{Var}[X_n],$$
when $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are independent; when they are also identically distributed, then $$\operatorname{Var}[X_1] = \operatorname{Var}[X_2] = \cdots = \operatorname{Var}[X_n] = \operatorname{Var}[X]$$ so
$$\operatorname{Var}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] \overset{\text{iid}}{=} n \operatorname{Var}[X].$$
Then, with the second property with the choice $c = 1/n$,
$$\operatorname{Var}\left[\frac{X_1 + \cdots + X_n}{n}\right] = \frac{1}{n^2} \operatorname{Var}[X_1 + \cdots + X_n] = \frac{1}{n^2} (n \operatorname{Var}[X]) = \frac{1}{n} \operatorname{Var}[X].$$

A proof of each property follows from the definition of variance and linearity of expectation:
$$\operatorname{Var}[X] = \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] = \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2,$$
and
$$\operatorname{E}[X+Y] = \operatorname{E}[X] + \operatorname{E}[Y],$$
and
$$\operatorname{E}[cX] = c\operatorname{E}[X].$$
Hence
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X+Y] &= \operatorname{E}[(X+Y - \operatorname{E}[X+Y])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(X+Y)^2 - 2(X+Y)\operatorname{E}[X+Y] + \operatorname{E}[X+Y]^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(X+Y)^2] - 2\operatorname{E}[(X+Y)\operatorname{E}[X+Y]] + \operatorname{E}[X+Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2 + 2XY + Y^2] - 2\operatorname{E}[X+Y]^2 + \operatorname{E}[X+Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2] + 2\operatorname{E}[XY] + \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[X+Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2] + 2\operatorname{E}[XY] + \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 - 2\operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 \\
&= \operatorname{E}[X^2] - \operatorname{E}[X]^2 + \operatorname{E}[Y^2] - \operatorname{E}[Y]^2 + 2\operatorname{E}[XY] - 2\operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y] \\
&= \operatorname{Var}[X] + \operatorname{Var}[Y] + 2(\operatorname{E}[XY] - \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]).
\end{align}$$
But if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then $\operatorname{E}[XY] \overset{\text{ind}}{=} \operatorname{E}[X]\operatorname{E}[Y]$, which causes the term in parentheses to vanish, and this completes the proof.
For Property 2, the proof is simpler:
$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[cX] &= \operatorname{E}[(cX - \operatorname{E}[cX])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[(cX - c\operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= \operatorname{E}[c^2(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= c^2 \operatorname{E}[(X - \operatorname{E}[X])^2] \\
&= c^2 \operatorname{Var}[X].
\end{align}$$
